# Adding columns across multiple tables with same column name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 10 tables named T1, T2, T3, ...,T10 and each store columns named ID, C1, C2, C3 ...., C100.

I want to create a summary tables which stores  the sum of corresponding columns i.e. T1.C1 + T2.C1 + T3.C1, T1.C2 + T2.C2 + T3.C2 and so on.

If there was only few columns I could have done something as:

```
select T1.C1 + T2.C1 + T3.C1 as C1, T1.C2 + T2.C2 + T3.C2 as C2
from T1
inner join T2
on T1.ID = T2.ID
inner join T3
on T1.ID = T3.ID
```

but I have 100 columns to add and I have large number of tables.

Comment: Please tag the appropriate RDMS  ... SQL Server, Oracle, ...?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming ID is a primary key in every table:

```
select ID, sum(c1) as c1, sum(c2) as c2 --,...
from(
   select ID, c1, c2 --,..
   from T1
   union all
   select ID, c1, c2 --,..
   from T2
   -- union all ..
) T
group by ID
```

Comment: should be able to use `select * ` if the columns are identical

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind going dynamic

```
Declare @Cols varchar(max) = '>>>'
;with cte1(N) As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
      cte2(N) As (Select Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From (Select N=1 From cte1 a, cte1 b) A )   --<< 100 Columns
Select @Cols = Replace(@Cols+',C'+cast(N as varchar(5))+'=sum(C'+cast(N as varchar(5))+')','>>>,','') from cte2

Declare @From varchar(max) = '>>>'
;with cte1(N) As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
      cte2(N) As (Select Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From (Select N=1 From cte1 a) A )   --<< 10 Tables
Select @From = Replace( @From+'Union All Select * from T'+cast(N as varchar(5))+' ','>>>Union All','') from cte2

Declare @SQL varchar(max) ='Select ID,'+@Cols+' From ('+@From+') A Group By ID'  
Exec(@SQL)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, you may want to consider the following.  The sub-query will normalize your data in an EAV (Element Attribute Value) structure

```
Declare @XML xml = (Select * From ( Select * from T1 Union All Select * from T2 Union All Select * from T3 Union All Select * from T4 Union All Select * from T5 Union All Select * from T6 Union All Select * from T7 Union All Select * from T8 Union All Select * from T9 Union All Select * from T10) A for XML RAW)
Select ID
      ,Item
      ,Value = Sum(Value)
 From (
        Select ID    = r.value('@ID','int')                            -- << Key ID (Case Sensitive)    
              ,Item  = attr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(50)')
              ,Value = attr.value('.','money')                         -- << Set Appropriate Data Type
         From  @XML.nodes('/row') as A(r)                         
         Cross Apply A.r.nodes('./@*[local-name(.)!="id"]') as B(attr) -- << Key ID (Case Sensitive)    
      ) A
 Group By ID,Item
```